# MongoDB LinQ "Select" method will really retrieve only a subset of fields?

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, subset

Searching across the internet how to retrieve a subset of fields in MongoDB, using C# official driver (but using LinQ as the base architecture) I found how to do this in MongoDB shell.

```
// selecting only "field" of a collection
db.collection.find( { field : 'value' }, { field: 1 } );
```

Then, I found at C# LinQ Tutorial the `Select` method, which is equivalent to this:

```
collection.AsQueryable<T>().Select(x => new { x.field });
```

However, the tutorial says the method "*is used to project a new result type from the matching documents*".

How to ensure this method will retrieve only the subset of fields and not the entire result and then select only the subset into a new object?

**Will the driver build the query command before retrieve the results?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver does not currently retrieve a subset of the fields.  If you need that functionality, you'll need to do it manually.  The ticket for this functionality is here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-456.  Feel free to leave feedback or vote it up if you need this.

Answer (score 1):

This is cheating... but:

```
//This actual implementation is untested and may contain small errors.
//The helper method has been tested and *should* work.

public static IMongoQuery GetMongoQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return ((MongoQueryable<T>)query).GetMongoQuery();
}

var temp =
    from x in DB.Foo.AsQueryable<Test>()
    where x.SomeField > 5;
    select (x.OtherField);

return temp.GetMongoQuery().ToJson();
```